# Jssor's nearby image partial visible Slider: Have to click on the slider for the pictures to load

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jssor

I am creating a website with bootstrap and i am trying to integrate the Jssor's nearby image partial visible Slider in a page. You can see the page live in [this](http://www.anagiannaros.com/articdesign/pages/projects/kingdom-tower-riyadh-beta-jssor-slider.html) link.
The problem with the specific slider is that on page load, only the first picture will load. Then, i have to click on the slider for the rest of the pictures to load.
Unfortunately, i do not have javascript knowledge in order to deal with this problem on my own so i really hope someone can help me. Thank everyone in advance for their time.

html-file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Artic Design - Kingdom Tower Riyadh</title>
 <link rel="icon" href="../../images/favicon.ico" /> 
    <link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/carousel-custom-navigation-buttons.css">
    
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (40KB) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = (jssor.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jssor-slider/jssor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jssor-slider/jssor.slider.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <style>
        .bubble { position: absolute; left: 93px; top: 21px; width: 135px; height: 84px; text-align: center;}
        .vertical-align-middle { position: relative; font-size: 11px; margin-top: expression(this.offsetHeight < this.parentNode.offsetHeight ? parseInt((this.parentNode.offsetHeight - this.offsetHeight) / 2) + "px" : "0");
        }
        </style>
 <![endif]-->    
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation Start -->
    <div class="navbar-wrapper navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top nav-top-height" role="navigation">
        <nav>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <span class="visible-xs"><a class="navbar-brand text-center" href="../index.html"><p>ARTIC DESIGN</p></a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="../../index.html">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../news.html">NEWS</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="../projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../creative-services.html">CREATIVE SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../team.html">TEAM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- Navigation End -->
      
    <!-- Main Body Start -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 hidden-xs">
                <div class="pull-right-md pull-right-lg">
                    <!-- Project Text Info -->
                    <div class="pull-right-md pull-right-lg">
                     <section class="project-info">
                         <p class="project-title tmarg-twenty">KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH, KSA</p>
                            <p class="project-info-text">Η φωτιστική μας προσέγγιση βασίστηκε στο να τονίσουμε τις τρεις ζώνες του κτηρίου καθλως και την οροφή του. Το υπόλοιπο σώμα του κτηρίου έχει έναν υποτυπώδη αλλά στοχευμένο φωτισμό ετσι ώστε τη νύχτα να “βυθίζεται” στο backround του ουρανού.</p>
                            <p class="project-crew">
                             <span class="project-crew-property">Lighting Designer:<span><br>
                                <span class="project-crew-value">George Tellos</span><br>
                                <span class="project-crew-property">Constructor:</span><br>
                                <span class="project-crew-value">Masic Holding</span><br>
                                <span class="project-crew-property">Location:</span><br>
                                <span class="project-crew-value">Jeddah KSA</span>
                            </p>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 carousel-col">
                <!-- Project Carousel -->
                <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      var options = {
       $AutoPlay: false,
   
       $PauseOnHover: true,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slideshow is auto playing, default value is false
   
       $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                  //Allows arrow key to navigate or not
       $SlideWidth: 600,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, the default is width of 'slides' container
       //$SlideHeight: 300,                                  //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, the default is width of 'slides' container
       $SlideSpacing: 0,                      //Space between each slide in pixels
       $Cols: 2,                                  //Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
       $Align: 100,                                //The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled).
   
       $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
      }
        };
     var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
     //responsive code begin
     function ScaleSlider() {
      var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
      if (parentWidth)
       jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 800));
      else
       window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
     };
     ScaleSlider();
     jssor_slider1.$Play();
     $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
     $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
     $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
     //responsive code end
     });
       </script>
                <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
                <!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
                <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
                    <!-- Slides Container --> 
                    <div id="slider1_container-inside" u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">  <!-- height: 1000px; -->
                        <div><img class="img-responsive" u="image" src="../../images/projects/06 THE KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH/Kingdom Tower Riyadh, Kingdom of Saudi Arabia.png" /></div>
                        <div><img class="img-responsive" u="image" src="../../images/projects/06 THE KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH/1.JPG" /></div>
                        <div><img class="img-responsive" u="image" src="../../images/projects/06 THE KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH/2.JPG" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="arrow_container" class="bubble">
                        <!-- Arrow Left -->
                        <div class="vertical-align-middle">
                         <span u="arrowleft" class="jssoral" style="width: 40px; height: 50px; left: 30px;"></span> <!-- top: 500px; -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- Arrow Right -->
                        <div class="vertical-align-middle">
                         <span u="arrowright" class="jssorar" style="width: 40px; height: 50px; right: 30px;"></span> <!-- top: 500px; -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
                <div class="pull-right-md pull-right-lg">
                    <!-- Project Text Info -->
                    <div class="pull-right-md pull-right-lg">
                     <section class="project-info">
                         <p class="project-title">KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH, KSA</p>
                            <p class="project-info-text">Η φωτιστική μας προσέγγιση βασίστηκε στο να τονίσουμε τις τρεις ζώνες του κτηρίου καθλως και την οροφή του. Το υπόλοιπο σώμα του κτηρίου έχει έναν υποτυπώδη αλλά στοχευμένο φωτισμό ετσι ώστε τη νύχτα να “βυθίζεται” στο backround του ουρανού.</p>
                            <p class="project-crew">Lighting Designer: GEORGE TELLOS<br>Constructor: MASIC HOLDING<br>Location: JEDDAH KSA</p>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Main Body End -->
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>-->
   <!-- this script resizes the slider's height so it will cover all of the usable browser's height. 
   $(window).resize(function WinResize1()
   {
    var usable_height = $(window).height();
    $('#slider1_container').height(usable_height-70);
    $('#slider1_container-inside').height(usable_height-70);
    //alert(usable_height);   
   })
   $(window).resize();
 </script>
    <script>-->
   <!-- this script resizes the bubble's height so it will be the same as the slider's height in order for the carousel's arrow to be succesfully vertical-aligned -->
   $(window).resize(function WinResize1()
   {
    var carousel_height = $('#slider1_container').height();
    $('#arrow_container').height(carousel_height);
    //alert(carousel_height);   
   })
   $(window).resize();
 </script>
    <script>
            jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's weird, not sure what's the problem, maybe you can update jssor.js and jssor.slider.js with the latest.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply!!! i updated the jssor.js and jssor.slider.js but nothing changed. is this a bug maybe? any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the following code, it is useless.

```
<script>
        jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
</script>
```

Please specify fixed size for `slider1_container` and `slides` container, note that the `100%` is not correct for jssor slider. See

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
    <!-- Slides Container --> 
    <div id="slider1_container-inside" u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
```

Comment: ok this solves the problem but causes another one: the slider does not cover the whole screen. if i have to specify **fixed** size for the slider system it won't be right for the specific site because i want it to be responsive and fit the visitor's screen whether he uses an xs screen or an large screen (4K). this is the reason i used bootstrap to begin with. so in other words, your slider system does not support a dynamic height and width which will cover the whole screen... :( is this correct?

Comment: I think so. Jssor slider should initialize with fixed size, and it will always keep aspect ratio while scale.

Answer (score 0):

i found a satisfactory solution to my problem. this solution won't work on the xs screen of the bootstrap for some reason so i had to use the traditional bootstrap carousel in the xs screen.
knowing that the Jssor slider should initialize with fixed size, the idea was to dynamically insert the "fixed size" on the Jssor Slider on each page load. see the code below.
i have zero javascript experience so it may turn out to not be the best solution out there. as far as i am concerned it is the only one though.
i really hope that Jssor will use this to release a V2 of his slider.
waiting for feedback.
thank you again all for your time.

```
<!-- Main Body Start -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 hidden-xs">
            <div class="pull-right-md pull-right-lg">
                <!-- Project Text Info -->
                <div class="pull-right-md pull-right-lg">
                    <section class="project-info">
                        <p class="project-title tmarg-twenty">KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH, KSA</p>
                        <p class="project-info-text">On the roof of the highest and most impressive building of Saudi Arabia light sources were installed, supplied by the TIC Riyadh.</p>
                        <p class="project-crew">
                            <span class="project-crew-property">Lighting Designer:<span><br>
                            <span class="project-crew-value">George Tellos</span><br>
                            <span class="project-crew-property">Constructor:</span><br>
                            <span class="project-crew-value">Masic Holding</span><br>
                            <span class="project-crew-property">Location:</span><br>
                            <span class="project-crew-value">Jeddah KSA</span>
                        </p>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 hidden-lg carousel-col">
             <div id="carousel-project" class="carousel slide"  data-interval=3000 data-keyboard=true data-pause="hover" data-wrap=true>
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-project" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-project" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-project" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <!-- Wrapper Start: slider images and captions  -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="../../images/projects/06 THE KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH/Kingdom Tower Riyadh, Kingdom of Saudi Arabia.png" width="789" height="1080" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="../../images/projects/06 THE KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH/1.JPG" width="717" height="1080" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="../../images/projects/06 THE KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH/2.JPG" width="717" height="1080" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  <!-- Wrapper End: slider images and the captions  -->
                  <!-- Carousel Custom Controls Start -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-project" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span u="arrowleft" class="jssoral" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 50%; left: 8px;">
                      </span>
                  </a>            
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-project" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span u="arrowright" class="jssorar" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 50%; right: 8px">
                      </span>
                  </a>
                  <!-- Carousel Custom Controls End -->
                  <!-- Carousel End -->
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 visible-lg carousel-col">
            <!-- Project Carousel -->
            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    var options = {
                        $AutoPlay: 0,

                        $PauseOnHover: true,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slideshow is auto playing, default value is false

                        $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //Allows arrow key to navigate or not
                        $SlideWidth: 600,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, the default is width of 'slides' container
                        //$SlideHeight: 300,                                  //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, the default is width of 'slides' container
                        $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //Space between each slide in pixels
                        $Cols: 2,                                  //Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                        $Align: 100,                                //The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled).

                        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                            $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                            $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    }
                };
                var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
                //responsive code begin
                function ScaleSlider() {
                    var usable_width = window.innerWidth;
                    var carousel_width = usable_width-(usable_width*0.33); //because of the left column
                    var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                    if (parentWidth)
                        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, carousel_width));
                    else
                        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                };
                ScaleSlider();
                jssor_slider1.$Play();
                $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
                $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
                $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
                //responsive code end
                });
            </script>
            <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
            <!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
            <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
                <!-- Slides Container --> 
                <div id="slider1_container-inside" u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden;">  <!-- height: 1000px; -->
                    <div><img class="img-responsive" u="image" src="../../images/projects/06 THE KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH/Kingdom Tower Riyadh, Kingdom of Saudi Arabia.png" /></div>
                    <div><img class="img-responsive" u="image" src="../../images/projects/06 THE KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH/1.JPG" /></div>
                    <div><img class="img-responsive" u="image" src="../../images/projects/06 THE KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH/2.JPG" /></div>
                </div>
                <div id="arrow_container" class="bubble">
                    <!-- Arrow Left -->
                    <div class="vertical-align-middle">
                        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssoral" style="width: 40px; height: 50px; left: 30px;"></span> <!-- top: 500px; -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- Arrow Right -->
                    <div class="vertical-align-middle">
                        <span u="arrowright" class="jssorar" style="width: 40px; height: 50px; right: 30px;"></span> <!-- top: 500px; -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
            <div class="pull-right-md pull-right-lg">
                <!-- Project Text Info -->
                <div class="pull-right-md pull-right-lg">
                    <section class="project-info">
                        <p class="project-title">KINGDOM TOWER RIYADH, KSA</p>
                        <p class="project-info-text">On the roof of the highest and most impressive building of Saudi Arabia light sources were installed, supplied by the TIC Riyadh.</p>
                        <p class="project-crew">Lighting Designer: GEORGE TELLOS<br>Constructor: MASIC HOLDING<br>Location: JEDDAH KSA</p>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Main Body End -->
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(window).resize(function WinResize1()
        {
            var usable_height = $(window).height();
            var carousel_height = usable_height-55; //beacuse of the navbar
            $('#slider1_container').height(carousel_height);
            $('#slider1_container-inside').height(carousel_height);
            var usable_width = window.innerWidth;
            var carousel_width = usable_width-(usable_width*0.33); //because of the left column
            $('#slider1_container').width(carousel_width);
            $('#slider1_container-inside').width(carousel_width);
            $('#arrow_container').height(carousel_height);
            //alert(carousel_height);
            //alert(carousel_width);    
        })
        $(window).resize();
</script>
```

Comment: the ScaleSlider() function is where the stuff happens